# Digital ocean set up: Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 23 column 3

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up my first digital ocean droplet and I'm extremely lost. I'm following this tutorial http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-rails-to-digitalocean-the-hard-way/ and I'm currently up to "Step 4: All the Rakes".

Everything was going smoothly, or so I thought, until I tried to run "RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate" which gives me the following error:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 23 column 3
```

From what I can gather the issue is in my database.yml file, specifically this part:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql,
  url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>,
  username: my_name,
  password: my_password,
  host: localhost,
  database: my_database
```

I think the issue is with the url but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. Coud anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Digital Ocean has a multitude of tutorials for setting up their droplets which are well written and up to date with their base configurations, so you are unlikely to run in to trouble (I have never had any trouble).

If you are new to Digital Ocean, and particularly if you are new to deploying virtual servers, I would start with one of their tutorials to get started: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials.